# Transferring Facebook session object between platforms

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

While awaiting a response to my question [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/parse-developers/sV7tC9nk5w8), the gist of which is:

1. I want to start Facebook login on my iOS app
2. I want to continue on Parse.com CloudCode where I can write to non-authenticated PFUser using MasterKey() so I can link the PFUser to the active Facebook session mentioned in step 1
3. I want to return to my iOS app and make the PFUser my active/current user on the app

I was wondering if it is possible to pass an active FBSession object from iOS to CloudCode (JavaScript)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can pass a Facebook session between devices. Simply get the FBSession and pass it to cloud code as you would any variable. Set a callback on the cloud code call to handle the passed back user.

You can also find useful background info on Facebook sessions here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.2#sessions

[fb ios sdk session for use with existing fb connect website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917087/fb-ios-sdk-session-for-use-with-existing-fb-connect-website)